# Set HTTP username/password from PHP

Tags: php, apache, http, permissions

I have a setup where files cannot be downloaded using a direct link, unless a username/password is provided using HTTP authentication.

I'd like to create a page linking to downloads which, when visited, sets the HTTP username and password, so the user does not ever see the HTTP authentication box. (However, if they try to directly download the file, they cannot.)

`$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']` and `$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']` provide a way of reading, but not setting, these values.

Comment: Why don't you just move the files if you don't seem to care if they are actually protected?

Comment: Wait. So you want to everyone to have to authenticate themselves... but you also want everyone who visits your site to automatically be authenticated? What's the point in doing that?

Comment: Perhaps the file archive is maintained on a different server than the PHP-based system that will authenticate on it.

Comment: or perhaps the intention is to allow download access only to users that *previously* have visited a _landingpage_ of sorts (which sets username/password). I think the question needs clarification.

Comment: Question needs clarification.

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity, ghoti's view is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bad idea! Authentication is for *ensuring you are who you say you are*. Instead, you're using it as an method to control access to a given resource.

If you want to force someone to go through a gateway page, generate a random query string and when matched, use `header()` to set the HTTP metadata and `fpassthru()` or `sendfile()` to send the content.

Answer (score 2):

You may be able to reach HTTP-auth links by placing a username and password within the URL:

```
http://username:password@archive.example.com/path/to/file.zip
```

Note that this notation may not be supported in all browsers, or support for it may be user-configurable within the browser.  You will need to test this on the platforms that are important to you.

Note that it's highly likely that there is a better solution to your problem.

Comment: I really don't think there is a better solution, other than not to use HTTP authentication.

Comment: This looked like a promising solution, but [it appears that Internet Explorer does not allow this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/834489)

Comment: ie blocks it, firefox raises a warning. Some years ago someone found you could create a url like http://bankofamerica.com:login@haxorsite.com and people would click the link believing it lead to the bank of america website.

Comment: @fluteflute - That's why I warned that it needed to be tested in your environment.  Without knowing whether this was for public consumption on the Internet or limited access on a corporate network that always uses a static Firefox configuration, the best I could provide was the warning.

Comment: Of course, the best answer to "How do I do this" is Joshua's answer: "Don't."